# Powershell: How to capture output from the host

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, output-buffering

I am using powershell to automate some tasks related to checking out/merging in TFS.  When I call

```
tf get * /recurse
```

I get a bunch of data scrolling by about the files that are getting checked out.  The last line generated by this command (assuming its success) is one telling the checkin number.  I would like to parse this out so it can be used later on in my script.

I know that I can do something like

```
$getOutput = tf get * /recurse
```

but then the output is suppressed entirely and I **want** the output of that command to be scrolled in realtime.  I would basically like to grab everything that just got sent to the output buffer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

tf get * /recurse | tee-Object -Variable getOutput

Answer (score 4):

The [tee-object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347705.aspx) in PowerShell 2.0 allows you to pipe results to two sources.  If you leave the second source empty, the results go to the console.

```
ls | tee-object -filePath directoryListing.txt
```

This will write the directory listing to both the console and a text file.